# Multiple iframes with individual back buttons

Tags: javascript, button, iframe, browser-history

I have a site with two iframes, each consisting of different content from my server inside them. What I want to happen is for each iframe to have a back button that works only for itself, i.e. `backbutton_1` only works with `frame_1`, `backbutton_2` works only with `frame_2`, etc.

These were the methods I attempted to implement, each to no avail.

- a) Putting a back button into the iframe with the onclick="history.back()"
- b) Putting a back button into the iframe with the `onclick="iframe.contentWindow.history.back()"`
- c) Putting back
  buttons into the parent site with `onclick="frame_1.history.back()"
  & onclick="frame_2.history.back()"`

Unfortunately, each of these methods only worked globally rather than individually.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can only do individual iframe history navigation to a limited extent with iframes on the same domain but practically it isn't a very useful mechanism because in reality there can only be one history sequence so individual history navigation conflicts with global history navigation. Once you diverge from one history sequence everything after it is erased so if individual navigation was used, global navigation would be impossible (or else it would unravel the very fabric of the space-time continuum and destroy the entire universe).

Imagine if you had a parent page A and two iframes B and C and you navigated forwards like this:

Step 1: A views page 1, B page 2 and C page 3

Step 2: A views page 1, B page 2 and C navigates to 4

Step 3: A views page 1, B navigates to 5 and C page 4

Step 4: A views page 1, B page 5 and C navigates to 6

Scenario using global history: if we navigate back twice using the browser Back button to step 2 as a whole you expect B to show page 2 and C page 4, and if you go forward to step 3 you get B showing 5 and C showing 4. Now the user navigates C to page 1. The user has now erased any history after this point because we have forked the history, so there is no global forward (it becomes greyed out). We can navigate back to step 3, 2, and 1, and we can navigate forward from Step 3 to the new step 4 (B showing 5 and C showing 1).

Scenario using individual history: if we navigated using individual buttons, and pressed the back button on iframe C twice, you might expect on an individual level that C moves to page 4 (where it was in step 2) and iframe B would be left at page 5. Now the user navigates B to page 7. Now the global and individual history buttons would be conflicting, because you might expect that pressing back on C could go back to page 3 (what it was in step 1), but where would the global Back move the two iframes to?

If you want truly independent iframe history I think that you need to track the user's navigation in your code, but be aware that the global navigation will be odd to use because of the conflict explained above.

Comment: I understand the dilemma you are accounting for, @guymid. Do you think there is a way to trick the iframes' created back buttons into working completely individually? Maybe a way for the button to only know its iframe's history, rather than the global history of the page? I'm starting to think I should stay away from history.back() altogether.

Comment: Here is an example of iframes with individual, working back buttons (the forward buttons do not work, however) http://superapple.ru/. I spoke with the creator of the page and he attempted to help me with my issue, but it is a bit too complicated for me.

Comment: Sorry, I did mean to add an actual solution to my answer, which is I think you have to do it tracking in your own code, but just be aware that the mix of the two types of navigation may confuse users. I've added that to the answer now.